# Monit dont work because cant find "if" program

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, server, monit

Im trying to configure monit on my ubuntu server for tomcat, but when I execute:

```
monit reload
```

It throws an error:

```
/etc/monit/monitrc:292: Program does not exist: 'if'
```

I dont know why it happends.

I added my configuration at the end of the file :

```
/etc/monit/monitrc
```

And this is my configuration code:

```
check process tomcat7 with pidfile "/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat.pid"
  start program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat start"
  stop program = " "/etc/init.d/tomcat stop"
  if failed port 8080 for 5 cycles then restart

   include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
   include /etc/monit/conf-enabled/*
```

What am I doing wrong? Why throws this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply have one double quote too much at `stop program`.

It should be:

```
check process tomcat7 with pidfile "/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat.pid"
  start program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat stop"
  if failed port 8080 for 5 cycles then restart

  include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
  include /etc/monit/conf-enabled/*
```

Comment: Im stupid -.- I have been two days searching for an error with monit and was only this. Thanks @boppy!